# How to avoid autocomplete form with Chrome in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, google-chrome, symfony

I have a form made with Symfony2:

```
->add('password', 'repeated', array('data' => '', 'label' => 'Repeat New Password', 'type' => 'password', 'required' => false,
        'first_options' => array('data' => '', 'label' => 'New password', 'always_empty' => true),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat new password'),
```

But in Chrome, the browser try to autocomplete the field New password.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should know better as a PHP developer using frameworks!
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: I know this, but I want to know how can I put this in a Symfony2 form not renderized in HTML.

Comment: The browser says: "The option "autocomplete" does not exist."

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
->add('password', 'repeated', array('data' => '', 'label' => 'Repeat New Password',  'type' => 'password', 'required' => false,
    'first_options' => array('attr' => array("autocomplete" => "off")),
    'second_options' => array('attr' => array("autocomplete" => "off")),
```

Comment: Thanks, but the browser says me: "The option "autocomplete" does not exist."

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome is the browser which autocomplete the form. But the error message is a Symfony2 Error Message.

Comment: @user2794692 that is because you are adding autocomplete to the 'first_option' array instead of the 'attr' array inside.